# Return within if statement?

Tags: java, return

```
public static String doLogic(){ 
    if (something){
        return input;
    } else {
        ...
    }
    //No return here.
}
```

How would I go about this?
I know I could do

```
int result = input;
```

In the if statement, and return it after, but I don't want to do that.

Suggestions?

Edit:
To be more clear, I don't want a return statement in the else either, as it's purpose is to re-run the method.

Comment: You could also return in both the if and the else.

Comment: What's your question/problem?

Comment: I would kindly suggest to reform your question. It is not clear what you are asking...

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted would work just fine, you need to make sure to include TWO returns, one inside the if-statement, and one outside of it, otherwise java will yell at you. But this is the proper way to solve the problem you are asking about.

so in your case, it would be:

```
public static String doLogic(){ 
    if (something){
        return input;
    } else {
        ...
    }
    return "";
}
```

Or, if you wanted the return to be completely encompassed inside of the if/else for readability concerns, you could include a return in the if AND the else of the conditional, which is acceptable java format as well, like so:

```
public static String doLogic(){ 
    if (something){
        return input;
    } else {
        return "";
    }

}
```

Comment: Or, as @DennisMeng points out, one in the `if` clause and one in the `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this cat. Here are two:

```
public static String doLogic(){ 
    if (something){
        return "something";
    }

    // The condition was not met, do something else
    return "something else";
}
```

Some folks prefer to use an `if` followed by an `else`

```
public static String doLogic(){ 
    if (something){
        return "something";
    } else { 
        return "something else";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
public static String doLogic(){ 
if (something){
    //do something to the input 
    return input;
}

  //do something else 
  return input;

}
```

that would replace the `else statment`. This way you won't have to define another variable `result`.